# Angular 2 cross-module open-closed component design

Tags: angular

Let's say my application module `A` imports another module `B` for a ToDo-List component `C`. `B` exports `C` and `A` imports `B`, that `C` can be used in `A` via selector.

When I add a list item to my todo-list `C`, it displays an error message, if the text field is empty.

#### What if `C` should support i18n and we don't want error messages to be part of `B`, but `A` should provide them?

**Runtime *injection* via component input**

It's possible to declare an interface `I` in `B` to be implemented as any object `O` implementing `I` in `A` and *injected* via component input attribute `todoListI18n` and `C` expects some `I` to be given to translate technical error names.

```
interface I {
    getMessageFromErrorCode(errorCode: string): string;
}
```

**Injection via token (I don't know if this is possible across modules)**

Maybe `B` declares an interface `I` module `A` must implement as a service `S` and provide it via token `T` and `C` requests an `I` via token `T`?

```
interface I {
    getMessageFromErrorCode(errorCode: string): string;
}
```

#### What if I say instead of 1.: `C` should not deal with error strings but components of `A` which are responsible for showing errors?

**Component *injection***

If there is an error, `C` will display a component `E` implementing an interface `I` which is declared in `B`. `E` is provided by `A` via token `T` and injected in `C` via token `T`. At least `E` is loaded via component loader?

#### What if I want to leave styling issues to `A`?

**Ignore Angular component encapsulation**

Is it a good idea to use css class templates/placeholder; no styling information in `B` and `C`, but `A` should define those css classes global?

---

So the question is whether it's possible in Angular2 to create cross-module open-closed components and are there some Best-Practices?

Thank you!